# MongoDB : lookup exact match without false rows

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 tables :

```
accounts:[
{id:111,name:'john'},
{id:222,name:'due'}
]

workoutTypes:[
{id:1,title:'a'},
{id:2,title:'b'}
]

accountrecords:[
{_id:10,workoutTypeId:1,accountId:111},
{_id:11,workoutTypeId:1,accountId:222}
]
```

I used this command to group all account records by workout type that match to the current account like that:

```
db.workoutTypes.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "accountrecords",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "workoutTypeId",
                    as: "records"
                }

            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        { "records": { $ne: [] } },
                        { "records.accountId": { $eq: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(accountId) } },
                    ]
                }
            },
        ])
```

the issue that I'm getting the records that related to both of accounts.
saw that eq command return a false value for non-match values.

there is an option to get only the record that matches to current account?

Comment: `accountrecords` -> This is a whole new collection, we dont have any clue about it and you mentioned three other collections. Dont mess up the details. Take ur time and post proper details to understand your problem better.

Comment: Thank you, have changed the issue.

Comment: `accountrecords` have duplicate `_id`s Please fix that as well. For the time being I changed one of them to `11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `localField` on `workoutTypes` collection must be `id`, not `_id`. Probably a typo from your side. Secondly, you need to use `$redact` operator if you want to restrict the content. `$match` actually works as expected, but it actually isn't checking whether all your sub documents are satisfying the criteria.

**Update**:

Try this query:

```
db.workoutTypes.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "accountrecords",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "workoutTypeId",
            as: "records"
        }
    },
    {$match:{"records.accountId":{$exists:true}, "records.accountId":{$eq:ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23")}}},
    {$redact:{
            $cond:{
                    if:{$or:[{$eq:["$accountId",ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23")]},{$not:"$accountId"}]},
                    then:"$$DESCEND",
                    else:"$$PRUNE"
                }
        }}
])
```

And the output is:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac8b2b8fb45830ff77cd33b"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T11:59:52.583Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T11:59:52.583Z"),
"title" : "Snatch",
"__v" : 0,
"records" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5acb1b666b08493b30deed92"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T07:51:02.294Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T07:51:02.294Z"),
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8b2b8fb45830ff77cd33b"),
        "repetition" : 4,
        "weight" : 120,
        "__v" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5acb1b6f6b08493b30deed93"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T07:51:11.878Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T07:51:11.878Z"),
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8b2b8fb45830ff77cd33b"),
        "repetition" : 5,
        "weight" : 130,
        "__v" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ace23aa1c4d590dc049e94e"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T15:03:06.824Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T15:03:06.824Z"),
        "repetition" : 124,
        "weight" : 32,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8b2b8fb45830ff77cd33b"),
        "__v" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ace23b21c4d590dc049e94f"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T15:03:14.293Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T15:03:14.293Z"),
        "repetition" : 325,
        "weight" : 235,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8b2b8fb45830ff77cd33b"),
        "__v" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5acc8ef5345125417cca18e3"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-10T10:16:21.709Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-10T10:16:21.709Z"),
        "repetition" : 123,
        "weight" : 456,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8b2b8fb45830ff77cd33b"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
 ]
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5acdf56afd5ca008d01b706f"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T11:45:46.192Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T11:45:46.192Z"),
"title" : "Jerk",
"__v" : 0,
"records" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5acdf597fd5ca008d01b7070"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T11:46:31.674Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T11:46:31.674Z"),
        "repetition" : 12,
        "weight" : 100,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5acdf56afd5ca008d01b706f"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
  ]
 }

/* 3 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ace336ed36c780e6ce76d5d"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T16:10:22.483Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T16:10:22.483Z"),
"title" : "Weight lifting",
"__v" : 0,
"records" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ace337ed36c780e6ce76d5e"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T16:10:38.708Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T16:10:38.708Z"),
        "repetition" : 21,
        "weight" : 100,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ace336ed36c780e6ce76d5d"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
   ]
 }

/* 4 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac8cf5ef14469169d8627e8"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T14:02:06.155Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T14:02:06.155Z"),
"title" : "Double under",
"__v" : 0,
"records" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5acc8f11345125417cca18e4"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-10T10:16:49.069Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-10T10:16:49.069Z"),
        "repetition" : 111111,
        "weight" : 222222,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8cf5ef14469169d8627e8"),
        "__v" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ace2d7b1c4d590dc049e950"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T15:44:59.722Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-11T15:44:59.722Z"),
        "weight" : 23,
        "repetition" : 123555555,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8cf5ef14469169d8627e8"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
  ]
 }

/* 5 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac8cfdd79a48216b3e048b0"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T14:04:13.670Z"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T14:04:13.670Z"),
"title" : "Push-ups",
"__v" : 0,
"records" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5accc1f1cd58a407c6562f79"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-10T13:53:53.933Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-10T13:53:53.933Z"),
        "repetition" : 123,
        "weight" : 456000,
        "accountId" : ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23"),
        "workoutTypeId" : ObjectId("5ac8cfdd79a48216b3e048b0"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
  ]
 }
```

Now you just **replace** `ObjectId("5a604b18280420c03e8d3a23")` in the query with your mongoose code `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(accountId)`  and you should be good now.

Comment: Great !! It's working!!
But still getting the records with [ ] values.

Comment: Replace `{$ne:["$records",[]]}` with this: `{ $gt: [ {$size: "$records" }, 0 ] }` and check..

Comment: I have changed the command and got this error: 
MongoError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing

Comment: I re-tested my query and its giving me proper results. Without `{$ne:["$records",[]]}` -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbaL6.png , With `{$ne:["$records",[]]}` -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0vYc.png . Post your documents which is giving false positive result.

Comment: Updated the answer, accept the answer if it worked for you :)